# pylibftdi missing libftdi libusb on Windows install

Tags: python, serial-port, ftdi, pyusb

I am trying to write a python bit-banging application to communicate with a FT232H eeprom using pylibftdi (over serial port).

I have installed the FT232H .dll using the installer provided by ftdichip (the default .dll install location is 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers'); but pylibftdi can not find libftdi or libusb.

[image]

An example of a pylibftdi base install on Windows would be greatly appreciated.

Note 1: I am aware of pyUSB, but this does not support Python 2.7.

Note 2: Under Linux (Ubuntu/Mint) the dependencies are installed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libftdi1
pip install pyusb
```

I need the equivalent for Windows 7.

Comment: Failed installing library. try with this module: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I can see PyUSB-FTDI on the link you provide. But I can't see anything for pylibftdi.... am I missing something?

Comment: Ask python but put to `system directory` ?  Copy your `dll` to `Python27\Scripts` dir.

Answer (score 4):

First install the USB driver as described here
http://embedded-funk.net/running-libftdi-under-windows/

For me this meant using Zadig.exe (http://zadig.akeo.ie/) to replace the FT232R USB UART driver with libusbK driver. (Remember to click options->List all devices in Zadig)

Second download libftdi. From https://sourceforge.net/projects/picusb/files/ I downloaded
https://sourceforge.net/projects/picusb/files/libftdi1-1.1_devkit_x86_x64_21Feb2014.zip/download

Locate your Python installation.For me that was c:\Anaconda3.

From libftdi1-1.1_devkit_x86_x64_21Feb2014.zip:

```
copy bin64\libusb-1.0.dll c:\Anaconda3\
copy bin64\libftdi1.dll c:\Anaconda3\
copy lib64\site-packages\* c:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\
```

Test:

```
python -m pylibftdi.examples.list_devices
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out this site: https://github.com/atelier-ritz/Python3.6-32bit--FT232H-libftdi1.4 -- the author has created a version of libftdi1.4 that works under Python 3.6

Comment: Does anyone know where to get, or how to compile, libftdi1.5 for Windows 10?  I used the libusbK driver with Zadig and it created problems that prevented me from using other, off the shelf, circuit boards that had an FTDI chip.